# How do I pass RegistrationKey to Azure DSC extenstion

Tags: azure-resource-manager, dsc

I have template below which errors out during deployment with error below. Samples on documentation page seems to be erroneous and don't even compile.

> "message": "VM has reported a failure when processing extension
>   'Microsoft.Powershell.DSC'. Error message: \"The DSC Extension failed
>   to install: Invalid type for parameter RegistrationKey of type
>   PSCredential.\nMore information about the failure can be found in the
>   logs located under
>   'C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\2.74.0.0'
>   on the VM.\nTo retry install, please remove the extension from the VM
>   first. \"."

Template

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "[parameters('swarmmanager1Name')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "swarmmanager1"
      },
      "properties": {
        "hardwareProfile": {
          "vmSize": "[parameters('swarmmanager1VmSize')]"
        },
        "licenseType": "[parameters('LicenseType')]",
        "osProfile": {
          "computerName": "[parameters('swarmmanager1Name')]",
          "adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
          "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPassword')]"
        },
        "storageProfile": {
          "imageReference": {
            "publisher": "[parameters('swarmmanager1ImagePublisher')]",
            "offer": "[parameters('swarmmanager1ImageOffer')]",
            "sku": "[parameters('windowsOSVersion')]",
            "version": "latest"
          },
          "osDisk": {
            "name": "swarmmanager1OSDisk",
            "vhd": {
              "uri": "[concat(reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('dockerswarmstorageaccountName')), '2016-01-01').primaryEndpoints.blob, parameters('swarmmanager1StorageAccountContainerName'), '/', parameters('swarmmanager1OSDiskName'), '.vhd')]"
            },
            "caching": "ReadWrite",
            "createOption": "FromImage"
          }
        },

        "networkProfile": {
          "networkInterfaces": [
            {
              "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', parameters('swarmmanager1NicName'))]"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "resources": [
        {
          "name": "Microsoft.Powershell.DSC",
          "type": "extensions",
          "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
          "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines', parameters('swarmmanager1Name'))]"
          ],
          "tags": {
            "displayName": "DSC"
          },
          "properties": {
            "publisher": "Microsoft.Powershell",
            "typeHandlerVersion": "2.26",
            "type":  "DSC",
            "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
            "forceUpdateTag": "[parameters('DSCExtensionManagerTagVersion')]",
            "settings": {
              "wmfVersion": "latest",
              "configurationArguments": {
                //"RegistrationKey": {
                //     "UserName": "PLACEHOLDER_DONOTUSE",
                //     "Password": "PrivateSettingsRef:registrationKeyPrivate"
                //   },
                "RegistrationKey": "[parameters('RegistrationKey')]",
                "RegistrationUrl": "[parameters('registrationUrl')]",
                "NodeConfigurationName": "SwarmManager.localhost",
                "RebootNodeIfNeeded": true


              }
            },
            "protectedSettings": {
              "Items": {
                "registrationKeyPrivate": "[parameters('RegistrationKey')]"
              }
            }


          }
        }
          ]
        },
    {
      "name": "[parameters('dockerswarmstorageaccountName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "apiVersion": "2016-01-01",
      "sku": {
        "name": "[parameters('dockerswarmstorageaccountType')]"
      },
      "dependsOn": [],
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "dockerswarmstorageaccount"
      },
      "kind": "Storage"
    },
    {
      "name": "[parameters('swarmmanager1NicName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "apiVersion": "2016-03-30",
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "swarmmanager1Nic"
      },
      "properties": {
        "ipConfigurations": [
          {
            "name": "ipconfig1",
            "properties": {
              "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
              "subnet": {
                "id": "[parameters('swarmmanager1SubnetRef')]"
              },
              "publicIPAddress": {
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', parameters('swarmmanagerpublicIPName'))]"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },


    {
      "apiVersion": "2016-03-30",
      "dependsOn": [],
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "name": "[parameters('swarmmanagerpublicIPName')]",
      "properties": {
        "publicIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
        "dnsSettings": {
          "domainNameLabel": "[parameters('swarmmanagerpublicIPDnsName')]"
        }
      },
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "swarmmanagerpublicIP"
      },
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses"
    }
  ],
  "parameters": {
    "swarmmanager1Name": { "type": "string" },
    "swarmmanager1VmSize": { "type": "string" },
    "adminUsername": { "type": "string" },
    "adminPassword": { "type": "securestring" },
    "dockerswarmstorageaccountName": { "type": "string" },
    "dockerswarmstorageaccountType": { "type": "string" },
    "swarmmanager1NicName": { "type": "string" },
    "swarmmanagerpublicIPName": { "type": "string" },
    "swarmmanager1SubnetRef": { "type": "string" },
    "swarmmanager1ImagePublisher": { "type": "string" },
    "swarmmanager1ImageOffer": { "type": "string" },
    "windowsOSVersion": { "type": "string" },
    "swarmmanager1StorageAccountContainerName": { "type": "string" },
    "swarmmanager1OSDiskName": { "type": "string" },
    "swarmmanagerpublicIPDnsName": { "type": "string" },
    "DSCConfigurationURL": { "type": "string" },
    "DSCExtensionManagerTagVersion": { "type": "string" },
    "RegistrationKey": { "type": "securestring" },
    "RegistrationUrl": { "type": "string" },
    "LicenseType": {"type": "string"}

  },
  "outputs": {
    "returnedIPAddress": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[reference(parameters('swarmmanager1NicName')).ipConfigurations[0].properties.privateIPAddress]"
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to pass in ps credentials do this:

```
        "protectedSettings": {
          "configurationArguments": {
            "RegistrationKey": {
              "userName": "whatever",
              "password": "[parameters('RegistrationKey')]"
            }
          }
        }
```

Comment: How does Azure know it shall be PSCredential, just denoting an hashtable with username and password automatically means in Azure that it's PSCredential?

Comment: I suppose, never seen it documented anywhere, i mean, i saw that you need to do this in the docs, but not why you have to do this